# Pattern matching puzzles

Tags: linear-algebra

Problems: I wish to have an equation for below data: 
$x = 2, y = 5$ 
$x = 2, y = 6 $
$x = 2, y = 7 $
$x = 2, y = 8 $
$x = 1, y = 9$ 
$x = 0, y = 10$

And Will you show me the **steps** to acquire that equation?

Comment: Did you plot the points on paper? What do they look like?

Comment: Yes. Its weird. On x = 2 there are 4 values of y that overlaps each other. Is this question don't have an equation?

Comment: There is no $y = f(x)$ satisfying these points. I assume you need to find $x = f(y)$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\qquad x=\min\{10-y,2\}\qquad$$

Answer (score 1):

The general mindless procedure of finding a function that goes over a set of points $(x_0, y_0), \dots, (x_n, y_n)$ is to solve the set of equations
$$y_0 = a_n x_0^n + \dots + a_1 x_0 + a_0\\ \dots \\ y_n = a_n x_n^n + \dots + a_1 x_n + a_0$$
These are $n$ linear equations with unknowns $a_0, \dots, a_n$. In your case, remember to swap $x$ and $y$.

Comment: You shouldn't do that.  Use _Lagrange's_ interpolation instead.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, could you please explain why this approach should not be used?

Answer (score 1):

First sqap the values for $x$ and $y$. Then apply the Lagrange interpolation. The first 4 points lie on the the line $y=2$ Then do the Lagrange interpolation explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405609/is-it-possible-to-find-function-that-contains-every-given-point):

After the application, the first 5 points then lie on the function

$$y = 2 - \frac{(x - 5) (x - 6) (x - 7) (x - 8)}{24}$$

Do this method again and the final function should be:

$$y = 2 - \frac{(x - 5) (x - 6) (x - 7) (x - 8)}{24} + \frac{(x - 5) (x - 6) (x - 7) (x - 8) (x - 9)}{40}$$

To get the function for your initial question, just swap $x$ and $y$. So the final function is:

$$x = 2 - \frac{(y - 5) (y - 6) (y - 7) (y - 8)}{24} + \frac{(y - 5) (y - 6) (y - 7) (y - 8) (y - 9)}{40}$$

Or in expanded form:

$$x = -446+\frac{4894}{15} y - \frac{1123}{12}y^2+\frac{317}{24}y^3-\frac{11}{12}y^4 +\frac{1}{40}y^5$$

[image: graph]

Answer (score 0):

$$x=0^{|9-y|}+2\cdot0^{\prod_{k=5}^8|k-y|}$$

Comment: Is this answer as crap as I think it is?

Comment: I think it's cute.

Comment: Not at all.  The solution set of the given statement form consists the given data.

Comment: I even can't use your equation sir. Will you explain how to use it?

Comment: He's using the (somewhat disputed) definition that $0^0=1$. If you check the values of $y$ that appear in your data, they each force the correct corresponding value for $x$ in the equation using this definition. No other pairs $(x,y)$ will satisfy this equation except for those in your data list.

Comment: Not quite: all other $y$ will give $x=0$.